# Emptying the contents of a text file

Tags: command-line

I have a text file in my home directory which receives data regularly through a cron job. Because the cron job provides dynamic data, I would also want to set a cron job to empty the file contents (the file must still exist). I don't need help with cron, just the command which can help with emptying the file.

Comment: Alternative: `tail -n +1000 file.txt > file.txt` should remove 1000 lines and keep the newest lines in the file (you never know when you might need some of the recent record to track something).

Comment: That is actually a better option than clearing the file on scheduled times.

Comment: @Rinzwind, that won't work since the file will be truncated before tail tries to read it.  You need to redirect to a new file, and then replace the original with the new one.

Comment: True @psusi :) there needs to be an extra redirect there.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The simplest way:

```
> filename
```

This is a less obvious way and probably less readable in a shell script by others, but it's all you need.

Because `>` is not actually a really command (it is bash builtin) you can't use:

```
sudo > filename
```

when you don't have permissions on that file. But you can use:

```
sudo bash -c "> filename"
```

Comment: what kind of permissions need to be altered because it says permission denied, i have done chmod 755 to the file already,or should i make it a new Post(i mean the permissions question)

Comment: @sosytee See my new edits.

Comment: so this means this cannot be made a cronjob?

Comment: @sosytee Of course you can, but use `sudo crontab -e` to add the cron job for root, not for you. Or change the file permission to 766 (or 666), not to 755: `sudo chmod 766 filename`. More about: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Comment: `truncate filename` is a little cleaner and simpler than redirecting empty output to the file and doesn't run into the problems with `sudo`.

Comment: @psusi `truncate -s 0 filename` indeed can make the trick. You can add it as answer.

Answer (score 23):

There is a tool created for that purpose:

```
truncate -s 0 filename
```

This will clear the contents but it will still be the same file (the [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) stays the same).

Suppose you "empty" a file using the naive method of deleting and recreating the file: the new file will (usually) have a new inode.

This inode is important because some programs hold a handle to the file "by inode". Even after you deleted and recreated a file those programs will still have the old file with the old content. The program holds the old file via the old inode while your recreated empty file has a new inode.

Some links to more details at the end of this answer.

---

Another way, maybe easier to remember:

```
echo -n > filename
```

This also keeps the same inode.

Note that both `truncate` and `echo -n` are not defined by [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX).

For POSIX compliance use `cat /dev/null`:

```
cat /dev/null > filename
```

Yet another way, more obscure and probably not shell agnostic:

```
> filename
```

---

If the file to truncate needs root privileges to write then the following lines will not work as you might expect:

```
# following commands do not work
sudo echo -n > filename
sudo cat /dev/null > filename
sudo > filename
```

This is because the redirection is done by the shell even before sudo is executed. That means that the write access to the file is done using the privileges of the user who runs the shell, not the privileges which will be granted by sudo.

A workaround is to defer the redirection to a shell executed using sudo privileges like this:

```
sudo sh -c "echo -n > filename"
```

Using `truncate` you do not need such a workaround because the write access is not done by the shell but by `truncate` which is executed by sudo using sudo privileges.

```
sudo truncate -s 0 filename
```

---

For some gory details about programs holding the file open even if the file has been deleted you can read the following:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028874/what-happens-to-an-open-file-handler-on-linux-if-the-pointed-file-gets-moved-de
- https://serverfault.com/questions/501963/how-to-recover-free-space-on-deleted-files-without-restarting-the-referencing-pr
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182077/best-way-to-free-disk-space-from-deleted-files-that-are-held-open
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51019714/does-recreating-a-file-reuse-the-previous-inode

Comment: it says Permission denied, have used chmod 755 filename but still the permission is denied

Comment: perhaps you have noclobber enabled in bash?

Comment: The most complete answer so far

Answer (score 4):

To automate this you can use logrotate. Just create a configuration file for the file you want to be emptied, add other settings and you can have it empty every day automatically based on criteria you choose f.e everyday, or when file is bigger than etc.

Take a look here on how to configure logrotate:
http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html

Comment: I favor this option myself. We use "file >10 Mb" -> "tar.gz it to backup" "empty file". And the backups get deleted after 900 days.

Answer (score 3):

`echo "" > foo_file` is a simple way of doing that, it will replace all contents of **foo_file** with **""** making it in this case, empty.

You can also use `cat /dev/null > foo_file`, that will read the null device and overwrite your file with nothing at all.

Comment: it says Permission denied, have used chmod 755 filename but still the permission is denied

Comment: Can you read the file permissions with your normal user please?

Comment: yes i can read the contents as normal user